# Summarize data in one row selecting MAX or MIN date

Tags: sql, view, max

I have a set of data from multiple tables on SQL Server. They include transactions on different dates that are related to a customers. I want to create a SQL Server view that has one line per customer. For date, I want to use the latest or earliest date. The date is in numeric format so I thought I can use MAX or MIN to create the view, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong that it is not happening.
[image: This is a sample of a data that I want to be summarized into one row]

In short, I want to have the total of AMOUNT_TR and for date I want the one of the dates in in case of the above example 20160608 or 20140228.

Comment: How do you identify the customer?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select customer, sum(amount_tr), min(date_tr), max(date_tr)
from t
group by customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming `customer_id` is your `customer` column.
you can create a `subquery` that contains the `max()` date and `customer_id` then join to your main `table` to use other `columns`.

```
select t1.* from 
tableA t1
inner join 
    (select customer_id, max(date_tr) date_tr
    from tableA
    group by customer_id) t2 on t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id
        and t1.date_tr = t2.date_tr
```